# iOS On Demand Resources not included PNG images

Tags: ios, xcode, on-demand-resources

I have a problem using onDemandResources (ODR) on iOS.

I added all resources of my project to a "TEST" tag, but PNG files also remain in the .ipa Payload folder.

[image: TEST Tag]

That is, if I export an archive and check inside the ipa file, in the Payload folder there are the PNG resources that should be onDemand.

It doesn't happen with the other types of files: jpg, xml, mp3, etc.

PNG files are also correctly inserted in the .assetpack file in the onDemandResources folder

[image: .ipa file Payload]

Use XCode 11.2.1 and MacOS 10.14.6

I have tried using a SceneKitAssets folder and in this way the PNGs are not inserted in the Payload of the IPA, but only in the onDemandResources folder.
But this solution is not convenient for my project, which uses shared resources in various folders.

Thank you